# Selection sorting of integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I'm working on a selection sorting code to sort an array of ten integers in Java. I've written this:

```
import java.io.*;
class selectint
{
    int array [] = new int[10];
    public void sort(int arr[])
    {

        int i = 0;
        int length = array.length;
        for(i = 0; i<length ; i++)
        {
            int min = array[i];
            int pos = i;
            for(int j = i+1; j<length; j++)
            {
                if (min>array[j])
                {
                    min = array[i];
                    pos = j;
                }
            }
            int t = array[pos];
            array[pos] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        selectint obj = new selectint();
        System.out.println("Enter any 10 numbers");
        String str;
        int num[] = new int[10];
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            str = br.readLine();
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        obj.sort(num);
    }
}
```

No compilation errors or syntax errors popped up. However, there was quite a logical error. I entered a set of 10 integers, but all that was printed after sorting was a set of 10 '0's. How do I resolve this?
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all usages of `array` in the `sort` method with `arr`, which is the parameter you're supposed to sort.

Any IDE should tell you that `arr` is unused here:

```
public static void sort(int arr[])
```

---

Also, you should remove the double initialization of `i`:

```
// remove previous `i` variable declaration
for(int i = 0; i<length ; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop you assign min inside the if to the array value of the outer value index.

min = array[i];

Might not be related but shouldn't it be

min = array[j];